# Reverse String before and after Slash ("/") character

Tags: javascript, html, css, unicode

I have Persian character in my page. when I display a string contains Persian characters within slash character in the text will not show properly. It should reverse the characters to show properly.

The correct text is:

[image]

But when it is displayed as:

[image]

```
361/شماره شد/1397/2
```

How to solve this problem?
I have tried css `direction` and `text-align` but they didn't work.

Comment: Pleas post the string **as text** and not as a image. It can't be copied to reproduce the issue or to create an answer.

Comment: unfortunately stack overflow text editor won't display it properly too! @adiga

Comment: Ah, in that case, you can keep both the images to demonstrate your issue and add the text to the post as well.

Comment: its :  361/شماره شد/1397/2

Answer (score 2):

Can you change your HTML? The only way I can make it work is by putting the Persian bit in a span and use `unicode-bidi: embed` on it.

```css
.e {unicode-bidi: embed;}
```

```html
361/<span class="e">شماره شد</span>/1397/2
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please try CSS property **direction** for your textfield

direction: rtl;

```html
<div style="display:inline-block;direction:rtl">1397/2/شماره شد/361</div>
```

Comment: the direction property specifies the text direction/writing direction within a block-level element. can you try adding **display: inline-block** too?

Answer (score 0):

@Amir Amiri i tried the unicode-bidi: bidi-override; inspired by @Mr Lister's answer.
please run this code snippet to see if this solves your issue

```html
 <div style="unicode-bidi: bidi-override;">361/شماره شد/1397/2</div>
```

Comment: In your output, the Persian part is reversed compared to the OP's screenshot.